# Restar dos variables obtenidas de SQL Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

Quiero hacer la resta de dos resultados en una consulta sql, las consultas funcionan sin problema al intentar restarlos me muestra un error

`$resultado= $data - $costo` y obtengo un error.

cada sql obtengo una coleccion y en ella solo tengo 1 valor

> ```
> Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int
> ```

```
public function dadoGalatia($id)
    {

         $data = DB::table('invoices')
            ->join('invoice_details', 'invoices.id', '=', 'invoice_details.invoice_id')
            ->join('payment_methods', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payment_methods.invoice_id')
            ->select('payment_methods.amount')
            ->where('invoices.id', '=', $id)
            ->limit(1)
            ->get();



        $costo=DB::table('invoices')
            ->join('invoice_details', 'invoices.id', '=', 'invoice_details.invoice_id')
            ->join('payment_methods', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payment_methods.invoice_id')
            ->select(DB::raw('sum(invoice_details.unit_cost * invoice_details.quantity) as total'))
            ->where('invoices.id', '=', $id)
            ->get();
        $resultado= $data - $costo;

        dd($resultado);

        if ($data) {
            return view('product/invoiceReport/PayBack',compact('data','costo'));
        }

        return response('', 404);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví tenia que indicar la posición del array

```
$resultado=$data[0]->amount-$costo[0]->total;
```

=)

Comment: Sin embargo tus consultas no aprovechan ni a Laravel ni Eloquent, tienes creados los modelos?